# Table locked in mysql server

Tags: mysql

I am getting following error but not able to solve it.

```
TABLE LOCK table `db`.`Trans` trx id 13610756 lock mode IX
RECORD LOCKS space id 1456 page no 2259 n bits 160 index PRIMARY of table `db`.`Trans` trx id 13610756 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 80 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 18; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 10; hex 32323731303239373931; asc 2271029791;;
```

I am not able to execute any DDL commands, Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: I have removed the MariaDB-tag, as your title specifies it is about MySQL. Don't just tag random other database systems (even if they share the same history, MariaDB and MySQL are **not the same thing**).

Answer (score 0):

I would check here, I think you are running into a concurrency bug

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=43591